# Equivalence test for paired samples with "statsmodels weightstats.ttost_paired" – why does the test always turn out non-significant?

Tags: python, statsmodels, equivalent

I am interested in running a equivalence test between two paired samples, namely `group1` and `group2`. I use `statsmodels.stats.weightstats.ttost_paired` (https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.weightstats.ttost_paired.html) as equivalence test.

The test’s null and alternative hypotheses are:

- H0: The difference between the means is outside the equivalence interval
- H1: The difference between the means is inside the equivalence interval

**Problem:** My problem, given a specific dataset, is that the test turns out non-significant even though the difference between the two tested samples is so small that thest should turn out significant (p < 0.05), given the boundary I chose (plus minus 5% from the difference between both sample means).

I am not sure if my "problem" is related to my code or the actual data. Therefore, I wrote a simple reproducible code below with two samples (`group1` and `group2`). The samples are almost identical as can be seen in the script, and therefore share almost the same mean. The difference between both sample means is `md = 0.1428571428571428`.

I set the maximum difference to be 10% via the following part of the code:

```
# Max percent change
percent = (md/100) * 10
# md minus and plus threshold
lower = md - percent
upper = md + percent
```

As far as my understanding goes, the equivalence test should turn out significant (p < 0.05) for this dummy dataset.

However, the resulting p-value is `0.46180097594939595`, hence the H0 is not rejectet.

```
import statsmodels as sm
from statsmodels.stats import weightstats
import numpy as np

group1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
group2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

mean1 = np.mean(group1)
mean2 = np.mean(group2)

md = mean1-mean2

# Max percent change
percent = (md/100) * 10
# md minus and plus threshold
lower = md - percent
upper = md + percent
# Test
test = sm.stats.weightstats.ttost_paired(
    x1=np.array(group1),
    x2=np.array(group2),
    low=lower,
    upp=upper,
    weights=None,
    transform=None)

print(f"md = {md}")
print(test)
```

**Question:** I wonder if I am doing something wrong in the code itself. For example, the `lower` and `upper` range should correspond to the difference `md` between `group1` and `group2`, plus/minus 10%, respectively. I cannot understand why the test still turns out non-significant? Is there a mistake in my code?